# Mail is going to spam folder using smtp javax mail

Tags: java

when I am sending mail to any Gmail user the mail is received as a spam folder, not the inbox.
How my mail will be received as an inbox folder.

My code:-

````
        String to = "rabinsamanta3344@gmail.com";
        // SUBSTITUTE YOUR ISP'S MAIL SERVER HERE!!!
        String host = "xxx.xx.x.xxx";

        // Create properties, get Session
        Properties props = new Properties();

        // If using static Transport.send(),
        // need to specify which host to send it to
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        // To see what is going on behind the scene
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        Message msg = null;
        try {
            // Instantiatee a message
            msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set message attributes
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] address = { new InternetAddress(to) };
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            msg.setSubject(mailDetailsRequest.getMailSubject());
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            msg.setContent("<h1>hi..</h1>", "text/html");

            // Send the message
            Transport.send(msg); ```
````

Comment: Try not sending spam

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please explain this "Try not sending spam"

Comment: The determination of 'spam' is made by google's algorithms, not by your code. If google thinks that you're sending spam then you probably are. Stop sending spam. Nobody likes spam. Send real emails from real email servers instead and your problem will go away.